# Redirect loop during http:// to https:// redirect

Tags: c#, ssl, redirect, https, redirect-loop

I am trying to force a page to be run under SSL, so I have implemented the following on page_load:

```
if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Helper.GetInstance().SSLBaseURL() + ScriptName());
        }
```

For some reason this is ending up in a loop.  Earlier today, I checked Request.Uri.Scheme, and it was resolving as "http", though I was clearly connected to https://www.domain.com/pagename.aspx.

Any reason you can think of why this page isn't correctly detecting that we're running under https?

Comment: What's the value of Request.IsSecureConnection when this fails?

Comment: It is false.  I have even commented out the redirect, browsed manually to https, and did a response.write on Request.IsSecureConnection.ToString().

Comment: Well, I decided to cheat, and keep a Session variable to ensure only one redirect happens.  It takes care of the looping issue, but the question still remains.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the way these particular servers are routing web traffic.

Comment: No proxys? That would be my only guess...

Comment: Keith, how did you end up solving this one?  I ran into the same problem when moving our site to the 'cloud'.  The load balancing messes everything up.

Comment: We found out this particular client was running a reverse proxy, so by the time the web traffic hit the web server, much of the information I could see in the Request object was not what I was expecting.  Like I said above, I put in a workaround to store whether I have already redirected in a Session["XXX"] variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this on the webserver side. If you're running IIS, it's not as simple, but you could enable the force SSL option and implement a custom error page for your 403;4 (I think that's the SSL required error) that redirects to https.