# Wordpress: htacess http to https not working for non-www

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

This is yet another question about enforcing http to https using `.htaccess` file. I've added code to my htaccess file and it seems to work fine if the original url is www.example.com or example.com/home. But for example.com it's showing an `302 found` error

I've already tried multiple other answers including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)
,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673170/htaccess-http-to-https-redirection-does-not-work), [this](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/redirect-http-to-https/) and others.

this is what my `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://isamatov.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How do I make it work for any kind of url request? Again at the moment it works for www.example.com or example.com/something

This is the error page I'm seeing when visiting example.com
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02XWJ.png)

Comment: You have 2 redirects going on. What do you want to be the end result? www or non www? You should choose one because Google indexes duplicate content otherwise.

Comment: @PanamaJack thanks for the response! I think it was just a caching issue and I just had to wait a day. It's working now, where do you see 2 directs? I know `acme-challenge`, `cpanel-dcv` and `pki-validation` setting were already there so I didn't touch them. I think they are for some admin panel pages. Ideally I want it to be non-www.